# MEAN - Get JSON part from Mongo _id (using: Mean)

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to return the Phone number (Only) when visiting this URL:

```
api/customers/57579110f686f6e11dac4b17/phone
```

I can get the following JSON from this URL:
api/customers/57579110f686f6e11dac4b17

(the entire JSON structure):

```
{"_id":"57579110f686f6e11dac4b17","phone":"5555555","lastname":"Lname","firstname":"Fname","__v":0,"address":{"zip":"17837","state":"Pennsylvania","city":"gvkgv","street":"bxihe"}}
```

I can get the address with this URL:
api/customers/57579110f686f6e11dac4b17/address

```
{"street":"bxihe","city":"gvkgv","state":"Pennsylvania","zip":"17837"}
```

I can even get the Street:
api/customers/57579110f686f6e11dac4b17/address/street

```
"bxihe"
```

But I can Not get *Just* the phone number from this:
api/customers/57579110f686f6e11dac4b17/phone

Why?
How would I go about doing this?

---

My Code:
*api.js* - Linked to server.js

```
router.get('/customers/:id', function(req, res) {
    Customer.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    })
})

router.get('/customers/:id/phone', function(req, res) {
    Customer.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    })
})

router.get('/customers/:id/address', function(req, res) {
    Customer.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data.address);
    })
})

router.get('/customers/:id/address/street', function(req, res) {
    Customer.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data.address.street);
    })
})
```

*Api.js* - Used in front end - (Angular.js)

```
myApp.factory('Api', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        Customer: $resource('/api/customers/:id', {id: '@id'})
    }
}]);

myApp.factory('Api', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        Customer: $resource('/api/customers/:id/address', {id: '@id'})
    }
}]);

myApp.factory('Api', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        Customer: $resource('/api/customers/:id/address/street', {id: '@id'})
    }
}]);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed an underscore on _id for findOne in the phone route.

```
router.get('/customers/:id/phone', function(req, res) {
    Customer.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing that out.
Missed copy and past error.